# How to handle postgres stored procedure out parameter in python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have one `stored procedure` in `postgres` which used `out` parameter.
How to use that out parameter value in `python`.

```
create or replace procedure test(id number,result out varchar2)
as
begin
result := 'Saud';
end;
```

I want call above `stored procedure` from `python`.

How to call that procedure from python with out parameter?

Comment: Class assignment? It's OK if so, but please say so.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a procedure like this

```
create or replace procedure test(in one integer, in two integer, inout three integer)
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
three:=one+two;
end
$$
```

In order to execute this procedure with psycopg2 use the following format.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='yourdbname' user='youruser' host='yourhostname' 
password='yourpassword'")
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("call public.test(%s,%s,%s)",(1,2,three))
result = cursor.fetchone()
print(result[0])
```

---

This should print 3. The thing is that you must bind all procedure parameters. Hope this help you....

Answer (score 0):

Use `psycopg2` to:

- connect to the database

  ```
  conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb")
  ```
- create a cursor

  ```
  curs = conn.cursor()
  ```
- execute SQL like:

  ```
  curs.execute("SELECT test(%s)", (1,))
  ```
- Fetch the result

  ```
  row = curs.fetchone()
  print row[0]
  ```

See [the psycopg2 documentation and tutorial](http://initd.org/psycopg/) for details. You should also read the [Python DB-API documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).